# А можно ли внутри  поместить ?

Tags: html

Знаю, вопрос смахивает на глупотню, т.к в интернете не смог найти такое. Просто дело такое, хочу сделать что то на подобии:

```
xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx                     xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Т.к очень мало работал с тейблами, поэтому чуток запутался =/

Первая колонка квадратная - одна ячейка. Там фотка будет.

Так можно внутри <td> поместить <tr>?

Comment: Первая колонка объединяет 4 строки. Это понятно.
Что насчет других двух колонок? Вам нужно выравнивание корректировать? Объясните плс подробнее, постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Скажем что вся высота 150. Первый столбик сплошь 140 на 140. Второй столб - состоит из трех строк по 25. Третий столб из двух строк, так же по 25.

Comment: Можно внутри ячейки поместить другую таблицу, собственно, все так и верстают.

Comment: да? я думал верстают в большинстве случаев сейчас дивами

Comment: я знал этот прием, но почему то сейчас в голову не приходил! Попробую сейчас. Только много таблиц это как то неряшно =/

Comment: @just в ВКонтакте тоже таблица есть

Comment: @just, чего далеко ходить? На этой странице - целых три таблицы используется. И вообще, таблицы никто не отменял, а использовать их надо там где это уместно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [код](http://pastebin.com/WvLeX0zq).

[image]